# Python - Looping through a list of strings to form new strings

Tags: python, string, list

Say I have a list of strings like:

```
list_str = ["Blah1", "Blah2", "Blah3", "Bad", "Yada1", "Yada2", "Yada3"]
```

How do I loop through this list such that, when I encounter "Bad", I can put all the strings before "Bad" into a separate string `Blah` and all the strings after "Bad" will be in another string called `Yada`

Essentially, when I print `Blah` I should get:

```
Blah1
Blah2
Blah3
```

Each blah has to be separated by a newline from the previous one.

Comment: What. Have. You. Tried. ?.

Comment: @septi: http://i.imgur.com/J5M9HeW.png

Comment: New to python, dunno where to start! Any hint?

Comment: The [official tutorial](https://docs.python.org/3.4/tutorial/) is quite good.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `itertools.takewhile`, which is set up to do just this.

```
>>> import itertools
>>> list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != "Bad", list_str))
['Blah1', 'Blah2', 'Blah3']
```

To get both before and after the `"Bad"`

```
>>> iter_str = iter(list_str)
>>> front, back = list(itertools.takewhile(lambda i: i != "Bad", iter_str)), list(iter_str)
>>> front
['Blah1', 'Blah2', 'Blah3']
>>> back
['Yada1', 'Yada2', 'Yada3']
```

Comment: +1 since i guess he never said that he needed anything after bad ... but by using an `iter(list_str)` you could easily get everything after aswell

Comment: hehe I already gave you a +1 but you could do `iter(lambda:next(iter_str),"Bad"),list(iter_str)` just for fun :P

Answer (score 3):

```
list_str_blah = list_str[:list_str.index("Bad")]
list_str_yadda = list_str[list_str.index("Bad")+1:]
```

is probably the easiest way ... although you could always just call index once and save it

```
bad_idx = list_str.index("Bad")
```

Comment: Do the ":" and "+1:" indicate ranges of some sort?

Comment: of coarse they do ... it is standard python slicing

Answer (score 2):

Not that I would actually recommend programming this way, but...

```
>>> SEP='---'
>>> [x.split(SEP) for x in SEP.join(list_str).partition(SEP + "Bad" + SEP)][0]
['Blah1', 'Blah2', 'Blah3']
```

Comment: aweful ... but awesome at the same time

Comment: (This is what happens when you start trying to learn Haskell in earnest...)

Comment: That's why I factored it out; it would have to be chosen--if possible--as something that *isn't* in the list. In practice, there's probably *something* that's safe to use (pick one of the more obscure ASCII control characters if it's a list of otherwise readable text).

Comment: Lol! We can have a list of unknown separators!  Then test each of them :P But hey, haskell is a good language then!